# Exception: object cannot be nil

Tags: objective-c

I have this function:

```
+ (double)runProgram:(id)program usingVariableValues:(NSDictionary *)variableValues
{
    NSMutableArray *stack = [CalculatorBrain programToStack:program];
    if (variableValues) {
        NSSet *variables = [CalculatorBrain variablesUsedInProgram:program];
        NSUInteger index = 0;
        for (id obj in [stack copy]) {
            if ([variables containsObject:obj]) {
                [stack replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:[variableValues valueForKey:obj]];
            }
            index++;
        }
    }    
    return [self popOperandOffStack:stack];        
}
```

When I pass it a nil object for variableValues the program crashes and the exception raised is that I can't replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject: with a nil object. I understand why the exception is being called but shouldn't `if (variableValues)` prevent that whole block from even being entered if variableValues is nil?

Comment: Are you sure it's not `popOperandOffStack` that's causing the crash?

Comment: there's no call to replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject: in there so it shouldn't be there.

Comment: valueForKey is coming back with a nil because there's no entry with that key.

Comment: I know why the exception is being caused I'm curious as to why it's allowed in that block if variableValues is nil

Answer (score 0):

You can have an NSDictionary thats not nil yet doesn't contain a key of obj .......

Comment: before this is called this code is executed: `self.testVariableValues = nil` and then `[self.testVariableValues copy]` is sent as the argument to that function